# how to stop a thread that worked in infinity loop from another thread linux(c language)?

Tags: linux, pthreads

in main, I create two threads
thread 1 for the first func
thread 2 for second func2 (it included while(1))

i try to stop func2 from func by using pthread_cancel()
but didn't work and after I finish with func the Linux return to func2 and continue the infinite loop
is there a way to stop a thread that worked with an infinite loop from another thread ????

Comment: Did you read the manual for `pthread_cancel`?

Comment: I like to use an atomic variable as a flag - it's 0 as long as the thread should continue, and something else sets it to 1 when the thread should exit, and it periodically checks the state of the variable to see what to do - keep looping or stop. Or have threads communicate via message passing, and have a 'stop' message as one of the options. `pthread_cancel()` is rarely a good option IME.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need pthread_exit();

```
#include <pthread.h>
void pthread_exit(void *rval_ptr);
```

So we see that this function accepts only one argument, which is the return from the thread that calls this function. This return value is accessed by the parent thread which is waiting for this thread to terminate. The return value of the thread terminated by pthread_exit() function is accessible in the second argument of the pthread_join which just explained above.

You can see this example below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_t tid[2];
int ret1,ret2;

void* doSomeThing(void *arg)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();

    for(i=0; i<(0xFFFFFFFF);i++);

    if(pthread_equal(id,tid[0]))
    {
        printf("\n First thread processing done\n");
        ret1  = 100;
        pthread_exit(&ret1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Second thread processing done\n");
        ret2  = 200;
        pthread_exit(&ret2);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;  
    int err;
    int *ptr[2];

    while(i < 2)
    {
        err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        else
            printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");

        i++;
    }

    pthread_join(tid[0], (void**)&(ptr[0]));
    pthread_join(tid[1], (void**)&(ptr[1]));

    printf("\n return value from first thread is [%d]\n", *ptr[0]);
    printf("\n return value from second thread is [%d]\n", *ptr[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I make two threads one for print(I need to print count 10 times in one second) and another thread for count(with while(1))  then after we count for 1 second the count function end and the thread exit and then computer back to to the count function and continue in while(1) and i cant stop it. i tried to use pthread_cancel from function print to stop count function but didnt work.